# Continued fractions with $n$ layers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, continued-fractions

Solve the equation

$$x=2+\dfrac1{2+\dfrac1{...2+\dfrac1{2+\dfrac1x}}}$$

Where there are n layers in the fraction

Comment: you can accept my answer if it was good, if you want more details ask :D

Comment: Nope I understood it after you explained. Thanks allow for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

the first thing to observe is that the number of layers doesn't matter. If $x = 2 + \frac{1}{x}$ it solves your equation, and simple continued fractions have a unique assigned value.

It's easy to solve $x = 2 + \frac{1}{x}$ though, just subtract two then multiply up to get $x^2-2x - 1 = 0$.

Comment: Did you mean $x=2+\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: @VincentTjeng, yes thank you. corrected now.

Comment: @user58512 I can see that the number of layers doesn't matter, but can you tell me the reasoning behind this?

Comment: @user61067, I did! If you solve the single layered one you solve all lays.. and there's a unique solution.

Comment: any questions?.

Comment: How do I prove this? Is induction enough?

Comment: @user61067, yes one part is trivial by induction, if $x = 2 + \frac{1}{x}$ then $x = 2 + \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{x}}$ and then $x = 2 + \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{x}}}$ etc.. The other part is that simple continued fractions have a unique value.

Comment: Ah perfect! Thank you!!